# How do I assign group level value - based on row level values - to df using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, data-handling

I have the following decision rules:

```
RELIABILITY LEVEL     DESCRIPTION
LEVEL I               Multiple regression
LEVEL II              Multiple regression + mechanisms specified (all interest variables)
LEVEL III             Multiple regression + mechanisms specified (all interest + control vars)
```

The first three columns are the data upon which the 4th column should be reproduced using dplyr.

The reliability level should be the same for the whole table (model)... I want to code it using dplyr.

Here is my try so far... As you can see, I can't get it to be the same for the whole model

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(effectsize)

df <- read_excel("https://github.com/timverlaan/relia/blob/59d2cbc5d7830c41542c5f65449d5f324d6013ad/relia.xlsx")

df1 <- df %>%
  group_by(study, table, function_var) %>%
  mutate(count_vars = n()) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  group_by(study, table, function_var, mechanism_described) %>%
  mutate(count_int = case_when(
    function_var == 'interest' & mechanism_described == 'yes' ~ n()
    )) %>%
  mutate(count_con = case_when(
    function_var == 'control' & mechanism_described == 'yes' ~ n()
    )) %>% 
  mutate(reliable_int = case_when(
    function_var == 'interest' & count_vars/count_int == 1 ~ 1)) %>%
  mutate(reliable_con = case_when(
    function_var == 'control' & count_vars/count_con == 1 ~ 1)) %>%
  # group_by(study, source) %>%
  mutate(reliable = case_when(
    reliable_int != 1 ~ 1,
    reliable_int == 1 ~ 2,
    reliable_int + reliable_con == 2 ~ 3)) %>%
  # ungroup() %>%
```

Answer (score 0):

The code settled on is:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

df <- read_excel("C:/Users/relia.xlxs")
df <- df %>% select(-reliability_score)

test<-df %>% group_by(study,model,function_var) %>%
  summarise(count_yes=sum(mechanism_described=="yes"),n=n(),frac=count_yes/n) %>%
  mutate(frac_control=frac[function_var=="control"],
         frac_interest=frac[function_var=="interest"]) %>%
  mutate(reliability = case_when(
    frac_control == 1 & frac_interest != 1 ~ -99,
    frac_control != 1 & frac_interest != 1 ~ 2,
    frac_interest == 1 & frac_control != 1 ~ 3,
    frac_interest ==1 & frac_control == 1 ~ 4)) %>% group_by(study,model) %>% summarise(reliability=mean(reliability))

df_reliability<-left_join(df,test)
View(df_reliability)
```

However, I would prefer to do this all within one dplyr pipe. If anyone has a solution I would love to hear it...